# Is my CPU overclocked?

Tags: windows, laptop, cpu, overclocking

My pc's info under the voice processor says this: "intel(R) Core(TM) i5-1035G1 CPU @1.00 GHz 1.19 GHz" but I can see from a pannel that my CPU offen is going at 2 GHz is this normal? I need to uderstand this because I'm having problem that maybe are related to my CPU speed..

Answer (score 1):

> I can see from a panel that my CPU often is going at 2 GHz is this normal?

Yes; The maximum turbo frequency of the `Intel® Core™ i5-1035G` is 3.6 GHz.

The processor supports a feature known as `Intel® Turbo Boost Technology`, which is basically a feature allowing the CPU to dynamically overclock itself, when specific conditions are satisfied.

The dynamic overclocking feature your CPU supports is not capable of being unstable.  I want to be clear, the boost frequency, is not actually considered to be overclocking your processor.  Simply stated, the processor was designed to run at 3.60 GHz, when certain thermal conditions are meet.

Overclocking would increase your processor's boost and base frequencies.  Based on the information you describe your processor is not being overclocked.  **The author of the [comment](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1268) had manually overclocked their AMD processor into an unstable state.**

> It's quite complicated I don't know what's wrong in my PC, I invite You to see my Stack Overflow [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59848225/assertion-failed-new-time-loop-time-file-c-ws-deps-uv-src-win-core-c-li) where I tell more about it.

As indicated by [Assertion failed: new_time >= loop->time #1633](https://github.com/libuv/libuv/issues/1633) you need to remove the CMOS battery to clear this issue.  Restoring the default settings is evidently not enough to solve the problem.  If you continue to have the problem you should continue to diagnose the reason your system clock is drifting. **Your processor running at a faster frequency is not the reason that is happening.**

Sources:

- [Intel Turbo Boost](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Turbo_Boost)
- [Intel® Turbo Boost Technology 2.0](https://www.intel.com/content/www/us/en/architecture-and-technology/turbo-boost/turbo-boost-technology.html)

Comment: @Flavié - If your machine supports disabling the option, then the option would be within the firmware settings, that is the only way to disable your processor from increasing it's frequency.  If the option does not exist then it cannot be disabled.

Comment: @Ramhoud Are there ways to solve my problem without opening the pc and so without removing the CMOS battery?